# cordova-plugin-whitelist codova plugin is not supported for ios

Tags: node.js, cordova, angular7, ionic4, capacitor

I'm trying to retrieve some data from server, using ionic 4, the app actually works fine on browser but when I use a real device it doesnt work, after hours searching on the internet, I found a solution that I have to install a Cordoba pluging called  cordova-plugin-whitelist,when I added this plugin the app worked fine on android device but not is IOS device, I checked capacitor DOC, then I found that I have to run this command :

```
ionic cap sync
```

after thise commande is executed,I got this message :

````
> capacitor add ios
✔ Installing iOS dependencies in 13.50s
✔ Adding native xcode project in: /Users/assenaneyoussef/Documents/Projects/Mobile_Projects/Test/ios in 103.53ms
✔ add in 13.61s
✔ Copying web assets from www to ios/App/public in 801.08ms
✔ Copying native bridge in 7.42ms
✔ Copying capacitor.config.json in 1.46ms
✔ copy in 868.93ms
✔ Updating iOS plugins in 8.30ms
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for ios:
✔ Updating iOS native dependencies in 13.43s
  Found 1 incompatible Cordova plugin for ios, skipped install
    cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.3)
✔ update ios in 13.47s

Now you can run npx cap open ios to launch Xcode
> capacitor sync ios
✔ Copying web assets from www to ios/App/public in 977.67ms
✔ Copying native bridge in 5.90ms
✔ Copying capacitor.config.json in 2.00ms
✔ copy in 1.12s
✔ Updating iOS plugins in 4.85ms
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for ios:
✔ Updating iOS native dependencies in 5.34s
  Found 1 incompatible Cordova plugin for ios, skipped install
    cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.3)
✔ update ios in 5.36s
Sync finished in 6.534s
```
if you noticed on the bottom of the message you'll finde a wierd message:
Found 1 incompatible Cordova plugin for ios, skipped install, is that normal ?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-whitelist` doesn't support iOS (because it's not needed). The message might be a bit missleading. 
Just check the plugin code, it doesn't have an iOS folder
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/tree/master/src

Comment: aah Ok, but I cant retrieve data from server on iOS device, so what do u suggest ?

Comment: Create a new question with a code sample of what you are doing

Comment: I think I dont need to create a new question because it's already clear, I can't retrieve data from nodejs server when I use real iOS device (localhost), what do u think the cause of this problem?

Comment: Well, localhost means "this device", so if you try to get something from localhost on a device, it fails because the device is not running the server, your computer is. So you have to use the local IP of the computer instead of localhost. See, that wasn't in your question, so that's why you should create a new one, or at least edit this one to provide this kind of information and the code you are using.

Comment: maybe you are right, I thought about it before, anyawy I will try to change localhost into my IP address, then I will get back to u, thank you.